# cd'ing permissions denied after enabling root user on mac os x 10.6.4

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, root, cd, permission-denied

I enabled root in terminal by `sudo passwd root` and then attempted to cd a rails site folder located on my desktop. I got the error `-bash: cd: /Users/fred/Desktop/sitefolder: Permission denied`

How to get rid of this error/ enable all permissions for root? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you called `cd` as root?

If yes, check if the owner of the folder is root. If not call

`sudo chown /Users/fred/Desktop/sitefolder root`

then check if the owner has reading permission. If not call

```
chmod 744 /Users/fred/Desktop/sitefolder
```

(this enables all permissions for owner and only reading permission for group and others). 
If you don't care much about that folder you may instead call directly

```
sudo chmod 777 /Users/fred/Desktop/sitefolder
```

giving all permissions to every user.

Comment: If I try any of those commands I am required to input my password but terminal rejects it although I know I am entering it correctly? Do you know what's happening?

Comment: Are you sure you spelled your password correctly? Check if caps lock is active. It may also be that you are not logged in as your user. Try call `whoami` to know who are you. As a last shore, call `su` or `sudo -s` and enter root password; then you can call `passwd your_user` to manually reset your user's password